# How to restructure document to optimize

Tags: marklogic

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287565) I had the problem of to many elements with that same attribute name(123)

We cleaned up the query and assessed the proposed solution, all queries remain at the same order of magnitude (15 seconds for the full size query), too slow for the application.

For completeness I repeat the queries here:

Original:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare namespace p4ns       = "http://www.nvsp.nl/p4";
declare namespace wijkns     = "http://www.nvsp.nl/wijk";

let $segment := ("Bruto","Netto")
let $codes := ("9766","9765","2162","2161","2159") (: full query is 4000 codes:)


let $zoeker0 := cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:element-attribute-range-query(xs:QName("p4ns:postcode"), xs:QName("id"), "=", $codes)) 
(:
let $zoeker1 := cts:search(/p4ns:postcode, cts:element-attribute-range-query(xs:QName("p4ns:postcode"), xs:QName("id"), "=", $codes)) 
let $zoeker2 := cts:search(/p4ns:postcode, cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("p4ns:postcode"), xs:QName("id"), $codes)) 
:)

let $inhoud1 := $zoeker0//p4ns:segment[@name=$segment]
(:
let $inhoud2 := $zoeker1//p4ns:segment[@name=$segment]/text()

let $r1 := cts:search(/p4ns:postcode, cts:element-attribute-range-query(xs:QName("p4ns:segment"), xs:QName("name"), "=", $segment))
:)
return $inhoud1
```

Accepted answer:

```
declare namespace p4ns="http://www.nvsp.nl/p4" ;

(: These might be external parameters. :)
let $segment := ("Bruto","Netto")
let $ids := ("9766","9765")
return collection()/p4ns:postcode/p4ns:category/p4ns:variable/p4ns:segment[
  @name = $segment]/string()
```

Both queries still have the expensive lookup of segment name attributes in the large documents.

The accepted answer says there is no really good solution but to restructure the document.

Now the next challenge is how?

Lines that I am thinking along:

- rebuild document
- split the document into two (or more) parts
- use fragments and fragment root
- use a separate namespace in the same document to split content.

Initially we designed the document in such a way that we organised all content in category[name="Oplages"]/variable[name="Oplage"]/segment[name="Bruto"] hierarchy. The identifiers are in "name" attributes. This is why we have so many segment elements with a name attribute.

So one option is to rebuild the document like

Oplages/Oplage/Bruto

In this way we need to build an index for all individual segments (400 of them) so this is why we did not do that.

Other option is using fragments, does it make sense to set up a fragment root at the segment elements? Not sure because the issue remains (searching one segment with a certain name in the collection for 400

So my question is: how to restructure the original document so my query performs in sub seconds response.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Mike didn't mention the option of Path indexes in the previous question. You can create an index on `/postcode/category[name="Oplages"]/variable[name="Oplage"]/segment[name="Bruto"]` specifically, by using that as Path pattern. That will help target the relevant fragments as accurately as possible.

I'm not sure what you expect as end result however. Do you want a list of Bruto segment values, or are you looking for the post codes that contain a matching segment? A lot depends on what you want as result. It can be useful to think about the issue from end to beginning.

HTH!

Comment: Yes, I mentioned range indexes but didn't suggest hard-coding the segment name into a path range index. Using that with `cts:values` might work well, as long as there are a small number of segment names to optimize: maybe just `Bruto` and `Netto`, for example. But there could also be an open-ended number of segment names, each of which would need its own path range indexes needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to use sub-fragments. It's too easy to write a query that accidentally loads all the fragments into memory. This use-case might be an exception and fragments might turn out to be the best way, but I'd leave that as a last resort. My experience is that it'll seem to work pretty well at first, but then cause more and more problems as you go on.

In your previous question I mentioned other possibilities. I'll review them here. The main trick is to remember that MarkLogic is a document-oriented database. So the document URI is the primary key, and documents act more like rows than tables. Structure your documents and URIs so that your most common queries will take advantage of those characteristics.

In MarkLogic the document URI is the primary key, and a lookup by primary key is simply `doc($uri)`. This is a very efficient way to query the database. Knowing that, you should structure your content so that your most common lookups are simply `doc($uri)`. You mentioned a structure like `Oplages/Oplage/Bruto`. I'm not sure exactly what that means, but what if you arrange it so that's a document URI instead of an XML structure? Something like `/oplages/{ code }/{ segment }`? Each document would be very small, with data for just one segment.

If you have metadata that you don't use very often, put it in a special document like `/oplages/{ code }/metadata.xml`. Or if it's used every time, copy it into every segment document. You understand your content better than I do, but the XML for a single document might look something like this:

```
<segment xmlns="http://www.nvsp.nl/p4"
 postcode="9728"
 category="Oplages"
 variable="Oplage"
 name="Bruto"
 updated="2014-08-12+02:00">
  1234
</segment>
```

With that XML stored at `/oplages/9728/Bruto`, a simple call to `doc('/oplages/9728/Bruto')` gives you the value. You can also call `fn:doc` with a sequence of many URIs. As you can probably see there's a trade-off around document size and how to structure the data.

The other possibility I mentioned is to use range indexes and https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values or https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-co-occurrences to query the data. This approach pulls data directly from a value index, instead of examining the XML tree. However this approach is still easier with small, well-defined documents. With XML like your original sample, which contains many values per document, you'd need position-aware range indexes and a carefully-written position-scoped query.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the suggestion of Mike and Geert and you can achieve what you want (I believe it is to get the bruto and Netto values for a postcode) in the following way:
Create two path range indexes, one for Bruto and one for Netto:
/p4:postcode/p4:category/p4:variable/p4:segment[@name='Bruto']
/p4:postcode/p4:category/p4:variable/p4:segment[@name='Netto']
Don't forget to register the namespace for p4

This will fail if you need those segments to be variable.
Then with the following code you can get the values for bruto and netto from the indexes

```
declare namespace p4 = "http://www.nvsp.nl/p4";
let $segment := ("Bruto","Netto")
let $ids := ("9729","9728")
for $id in $ids
return ($id,
  cts:value-co-occurrences(
    cts:path-reference("/p4:postcode/p4:category/p4:variable/p4:segment[@name='Bruto']"),
    cts:path-reference("/p4:postcode/p4:category/p4:variable/p4:segment[@name='Netto']"),(),
    cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("p4:postcode"),xs:QName("id"),$id)))
```

This will give you back a sequence of ids with the bruto and netto values like :

```
9729 (: id :)
<cts:co-occurrence xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <cts:value xsi:type="xs:int">4321</cts:value> (: bruto value :)
  <cts:value xsi:type="xs:int">2000</cts:value> (: netto value :)
</cts:co-occurrence>
```

Or you could create a path range index on /p4:postcode/@id as well and do:

```
declare namespace p4 = "http://www.nvsp.nl/p4";
let $segments := ("Bruto","Netto")
for $segment in $segments
return ($segment,
  cts:value-co-occurrences(
    cts:path-reference("/p4:postcode/@id"),
    cts:path-reference(fn:concat("/p4:postcode/p4:category/p4:variable/p4:segment[@name='",$segment,"']")),()))
```

and that will give you back the postcode plus the given segment value:

```
Bruto (: segment name :)
<cts:co-occurrence xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <cts:value xsi:type="xs:int">9728</cts:value>  (: postcode :)
  <cts:value xsi:type="xs:int">1234</cts:value>  (: segment value :)
</cts:co-occurrence>
```